# Positioning graphics or jpanel in the center of the window on resize

Tags: java

In my program I use cardLayout to switch between panels ( each panel is used as a separate class ). One of the panels, lets call it the board, contains graphics.

As I understand the size of the panel is fit to the window size or jframe, so when I resize window jpanel size and graphics in it also change in size.

How I can position graphics in the center of the window when it resizes? Or as I understand how I can position jpanel in the center so the graphics which it contains will be located in the center of the window also?

My graphics I use in program could be the simple square grid ( which is fixed in number of cells ), here's the code, COLS and ROWS are constants while SIZE ( size of a cell ) is adjusted to the size of the window and can be changed:

```
       g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        for( int i = 1; i < COLS; i ++ ){
            for( int j = 1; j < ROWS; j ++ ){
                g.drawLine(0, j*SIZE, COLS*SIZE, j*SIZE);
                g.drawLine(i*SIZE, 0, i*SIZE, ROWS*SIZE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- Get your JPanel's width and height from within the paintComponent method and use this information to scale your graphics.
- Nest your drawing JPanel  inside of another JPanel, a "wrapper" JPanel that uses GridBagLayout. If on the drawing JPanel is added and without GridBagConstraints, it will remain centralized in the wrapper JPanel.

Comment: tnx for solution, I'll try 2nd option

Comment: @Ir0nm: best of luck with it!!

Answer (score 0):

if i want to draw a line of some length that is centered i determine how big in width is this thing i'm drawing. if its 50 and my panel width is 800, i do 400 - 25 or 375 as my start origin to draw.  so rather than draw from 0, i draw from the start origin. If i'm drawing 8 things side by side and i want the whole 8 centered, i get the total size that fills, as the size of what i'm drawing and find out again how much space i have around it and on each column i draw offsetting it that much.

Comment: I can't do that because I use grid constraints and I need to recalculate the position of each border and that is too hard and many calculations

Comment: well in a loop were i want my line to start at i * size i rewrite this as offset + i * size.  so if x is going up 25 each time size is incremented the whole thing moves.

Comment: if you got 400 space around the whole series of items you draw horizontally,  your offset is 200. if you have size of 25 rather than draw at 0, 25, 50, by adding the offset then doing + i * size you print to 200 225 250 etc.